# Unexpected primary-expression before '>' token found in CodeBlocks C++

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

The following codes can compile very well in VC10:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>



#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>


    template <typename T>
    class  Coordinate
    {
    public:
        T x_;  ///< x_coordinate
        T y_;  ///< y_coordinate
        /**
        * Default constructor
        */
        Coordinate():x_(0),y_(0){};
        /**
        * Default deconstructor
        */
        ~Coordinate() {};

        /**
        * distance between two points
        */
        template<typename outputType>
        outputType distance( const Coordinate<T> &obj) const
        {
            outputType dis_x = x_-obj.x_;
            outputType dis_y = y_-obj.y_;
            return static_cast<outputType>(sqrt( (double)(dis_x*dis_x)+(double)(dis_y*dis_y)));
        }
    };




    /**
    * This function is used to calculate the distance between two points
    * @relates Coordinate
    * @param pt1 Point 1
    * @param pt2 Point 2
    * @return the distance
    */
    template<typename BaseType, typename OutputType >
    inline OutputType Distance(const Coordinate<BaseType> &pt1, const Coordinate<BaseType> &pt2)
    {
        OutputType dis;

        dis = pt2.distance<OutputType>(pt1);

        return dis;
    }

    /**
    * This function is used to calculate the distance between one point with
    * an array of data sets.
    */
    template<typename BaseType, typename OutputType>
    void Distance(const std::vector<Coordinate<BaseType> > &pt_array,
        const Coordinate<BaseType> &pt,
        std::vector<OutputType> &dis_array)
    {
        int len = pt_array.size();
        dis_array.resize(len);
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            dis_array[i] = pt.distance<OutputType>(pt_array[i]);
        }
    }


int main()
{


  int a;
  Coordinate<float> pt1;
  Coordinate<float> pt2;

  pt1.x_ = 2;
  pt1.y_ = 3;
  pt2.x_ = 4;
  pt2.y_ = 5;

  a = Distance<float,int>(pt1,pt2);
  std::cout<<a<<std::endl;

return 1;
}
```

However, when it was compiled in ubuntu linux CodeBlocks with g++ 4.6, the following errors occur:

```
 In function ‘OutputType Distance(const Coordinate<BaseType>&, const Coordinate<BaseType>&)’:
           error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
 In function ‘void Distance(const std::vector<Coordinate<BaseType> >&, const Coordinate<BaseType>&, std::vector<OutputType>&)’:
  error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `pt2` is of template type, you have to specify that the function called is a template:

```
dis = pt2.template distance<OutputType>(pt1);
```

Visual Studio can work this out without the `template` keyword, but this isn't standard behaviour.

Comment: Many thanks, and it works. But why in VC10 there is no need to specify the template? It would be nice if you could provide me the the source. Thanks!

Comment: @feelfree: Microsoft C++ doesn't perform the two-stage name lookup (once when the template is defined, and once when it's implemented) specified by the C++ standard. Instead, it defers all name lookup until the template is instantiated. At that point, it can tell whether a dependent name refers to a member, a type, or a template without having to be told; so as an "extension" it allows you to omit the `template` or `typename` specifiers that other compilers require.